# How to administratively invalidate a session that used "Remember Me" option?

Tags: session, symfony-2.1, remember-me

I'm using Symfony 2.1.6 and PdoSessionStorage. I'm trying to add the same functionality that Facebook has to my application where you can show a user all the active sessions they have with the website (showing device type and location based on IP) and allow them to end any session if it looks suspicious.

Deleting the record from the PdoSessionStorage table doesn't work as the record is re-created automatically by Symfony again as soon as I perform activity again in that session (instead of Symfony detecting that the session was already removed and thus forcing the user to re-authenticate).

Is there any option to force a session that used "Remember Me" to re-authenticate with the system?

Thanks for any help.