# Force reauthentication after user permissions have been changed

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

In my application I can change user permissions and roles in backend.

When a user is logged in and I remove a role of the user, the user can still access content which he actually is not permitted to access anymore, because he is missing the role. The changes take effect only when the user reauthenticates himself with logout/login.

So my question is, can I access the session of a logged in user (not me)? I know I can access my own session and destroy it which forces me to login again. But I want to get the session of any user who is logged in. Is this possible? I could not find any resources about that.

I use [**PdoSessionStorage**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) with symfony2.1 and fosuserbundle.

Comment: also asked here, with no answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184484/how-to-administratively-invalidate-a-session-that-used-remember-me-option

Comment: @MDrollette I feel this will neve be answered. I think the only solution might be a custom session manager

Comment: It would just be a matter of storing the user ID along with the session ID in the session table. Doesn't sound particularly difficult but i'm not sure of the best approach either.

Comment: @MDrollette I was thinking extactly about the same approch. I think I am going to give it a try and publish updates here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make your user class implement `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface`.

If you return `false` from the `isEqualTo()` method, the user will be reauthenticated. Use that method to compare only those properties that when changed should force reauthentication — roles in your case.

Comment: +1 Ok I understand that. Where do I have to make this check? I have to make it on every request?

Comment: Just make your user class implement the interface. You'll be forced to implement the `isEqualTo()` method. The rest is handled by Symfony.

Answer (score -1):

You can get around this issue by following an approach similar to what I did:

1. When user logs in, store all permissions in session along with a checksum of those permissions.
2. Store the same checksum in a database, or on disk, against that user ID
3. Whenever the user makes a request, verify that the checksum on disk matches the one in session for that user. If it is different, reload the permissions into the user's session
4. When you change the permissions, update the checksum in the database (or on disk) that is stored against that user. This will trigger a resync on their next request.

Comment: Hm looks interesting but complex aswell. Is this some kind of helpdesk you are developing?

Comment: @artworkadシ its not really complex, its using basic symfony2 components like the service container, security context and request object to determine what to do with permissions.

Comment: @Jaitsu, the Symfony built-in solution is *so* simple, you'll laugh hysterically. See my answer. ;)

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov my solution will re-sync permissions with the user's session but won't force the user to log back in, although I never knew of the EquatableInterface behaviour :)

Comment: @Jaitsu, AFAIK, the `EquatableInterface` just reloads the user object — without forcing the user to relogin.

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov all I could see in the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token::setUser()` method is that it calls `setAuthenticated(false)` on line 112?