# How to logout banned or changed users in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I would like to logout users if they are banned or if there roles changed but I can't find any solutions with Symfony 4 version.

I've tried this line in my security.yaml :

```
always_authenticate_before_granting: true
```

```
logout_on_user_change: true
```

I don't have any errors with this lines but they do nothing

Here is my security.yaml file:

```
security:

    encoders:
      App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers

    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous

    role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER # user front-end
      ROLE_EDITOR:   ROLE_USER # rédacteur (minimum level to access back-office)
      ROLE_MODERATOR:   ROLE_USER # modérateur (forum et commentaire)
      ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_EDITOR] # admin
      ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_ADMIN] # super-admin

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
              entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker


            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

            remember_me:
              secret: '%kernel.secret%'
              lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
              path: /
            logout:
              path: /logout


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_MODERATOR }
        - { path: ^/account/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Maybe see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115882/force-reauthentication-after-user-permissions-have-been-changed

Comment: Great, it works thank you!